# Why does this regular expression pattern cause the parser to hang given certain input?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regex which parses a TNS names file.  However it hangs on certain TNSNames files.  The problem has been tracked down to whether the string being matched has a space after the `HOST=` part or not.  Ignoring the appropriateness of the pattern, and how to fix the issue (this has been dealt with) what I want to know is why does the change in input cause the application to hang, as the `Regex.Match(invalid)` call never returns

```
string valid = "SOMENAME = (DESCRIPTION= " + 
                "(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST = localhost) (PORT=1521) ) " + 
                "(CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=ABC)))";

string invalid = "SOMENAME = (DESCRIPTION= " + 
                "(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST =localhost) (PORT=1521) ) " + 
                "(CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=ABC)))";
Regex regex = new Regex("SOMENAME" + @"[^=]*=(\s|[^H]*)*HOST\s*=\s(?<host>[^\)]*)\s*\)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//this line is fine
Match match = regex.Match(valid);  
//this line causes visual studio to hang
match = regex.Match(invalid);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most certainly caused by [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), and the culprit is

```
(\s|[^H]*)*
```

because `\s` and `[^H]` can match the same content, and because you've nested two infinite quantifiers.

`[^H]*` alone matches exactly the same content and is not prone to backtracking, so try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("SOMENAME" + @"[^=]*=([^H]*)HOST\s*=\s(?<host>[^\)]*)\s*\)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```